# Find the coefficients of product

Tags: combinatorics, polynomials, binomial-coefficients

Given the following product,
$$(1+ax)(1+a^2x)(1+a^3x)\cdots (1+a^mx) $$
where $a$ is some real number which will be taken to be unity in the end. I want to know the coefficient of general term of expansion $x^p$. I know that the coefficient of $x^p$ comes from choosing $p$ terms from $m$, but the terms will reduce because some kinds of products have the same coefficients. How to write the coefficient step by step?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would try induction over $m$. Define
$$
P_m=(1+aX)(1+a^2X)\dots(1+a^m X).
$$
Lets denote the coefficients of $P_m$ by $c_p^m$ so that
$$
P_m=\sum_{p=0}^m c_p^m X^p.
$$
Assume that $m\in \mathbb N$ and that we know the coefficients $c_p^m$. Now what do the coefficients for $P_{m+1}$ look like?

Notice that $P_{m+1}=P_m \cdot (1+a^{m+1}X)$ and thus
$$
P_{m+1}=\sum_{p=0}^m c_p^m x^p \cdot (1+a^{m+1}X) = \sum_{p=0}^m c_p^m X^p + c_p^m a^{m+1} X^{p+1}=\left(\sum_{p=0}^m (c_p^m + c_{p-1}^{m}a^{m+1})X^p\right) + c_m^ma^{m+1}X^{m+1}
$$
but also by defintion
$$
P_{m+1}=\sum_{p=0}^{m+1} c_p^{m+1} X^p.
$$
and thus by comparing the coefficients we find
$$
c_p^m+c_{p-1}^{m}a^{m+1}=c_p^{m+1}\quad\text{and}\quad c_{m+1}^{m+1}=c_m^ma^{m+1}
$$

Comment: Nice Job! The expansion should start from $p=0$.

Comment: Oh yes thanks, corrected that. But does that really help to find a closed form? I wouldnt know how to find an explicit form for $c_p^m$ from that -- would be guess work

Answer (score 4):

Products of this type are known to be *generalisations* of the binomial
\begin{align*}
(1+x)^m=\sum_{k=0}^m\binom{m}{k}x^k
\end{align*}
Often such generalisations are written with $q$ instead of $a$ and here I'll follow this convention. We denote with $[x^p]$ the coefficient of $x^p$ in a series and want to find
\begin{align*}
[x^p]\left(1+qx\right)\left(1+q^2x\right)\cdots\left(1+q^mx\right)=[x^p]\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1+q^kx\right)\tag{1}
\end{align*}

According to the *[q-binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem)* the following is valid
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(1+q^kx\right)=\sum_{k=0}^mq^{\binom{k}{2}}\binom{m}{k}_q x^k}\tag{2}
\end{align*}
with $\binom{m}{k}_{q}$ the so-called *[q-binomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient#q-binomial_theorem)*. The q-binomial coefficients follow a recurrence relation similar to the binomial coefficients, namely
\begin{align*}
\binom{m}{k}_q&=q^k\binom{m-1}{k}_q+\binom{m-1}{k-1}_q\qquad\qquad 1\leq k\leq m\tag{3.1}\\
\binom{m}{0}_q&=\binom{m}{m}_q=1\tag{3.2}\\
\binom{m}{1}_q&=\binom{m}{m-1}_q=1+q+\cdots+q^{k-1}\tag{3.3}
\end{align*}
We can now transform (1) to use the sum formula in (2) so that we can extract the coefficient of $x^p$.

> We obtain from (1) and (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^p]}\color{blue}{\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1+q^kx\right)}
> &=[x^p]\prod_{k=1}^m\left(1+q^{k-1}(qx)\right)\tag{4.1}\\
> &=[x^p]\prod_{k=0}^{m-1}\left(1+q^k(qx)\right)\tag{4.2}\\
> &=[x^p]\sum_{k=0}^mq^{\binom{k}{2}}\binom{m}{k}_q (qx)^k\tag{4.3}\\
> &=[x^p]\sum_{k=0}^mq^{\binom{k+1}{2}}\binom{m}{k}_q x^k\tag{4.4}\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=q^{\binom{p+1}{2}}\binom{m}{p}_q}\tag{4.5}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (4.1) we write $q^k=q^{k-1}q$.
- In (4.2) we shift the index to start with $k=0$ and are now able to apply (2).
- In (4.3) we apply (2), replacing $x$ with $qx$.
- In (4.4) we use $\binom{q}{2}+q=\frac{1}{2}q(q-1)+q=\frac{1}{2}q(q+1)=\binom{q+1}{2}$.
- In (4.5) we select the coefficient of $x^p$.

**Example $m=5, p=3$:** Let's calculate a small example. We obtain with $m=5$ and $p=3$:
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{[}&\color{blue}{x^3]\prod_{k=1}^5\left(1+q^kx\right)}=q^{\binom{4}{2}}\binom{5}{2}_q\tag{$\rightarrow 4.1, 4.5$}\\
&=q^6\left(q^2\binom{4}{2}_q+\binom{4}{1}_q\right)\tag{$\rightarrow 3.1$}\\
&=q^6\left(q^2\left(q^2\binom{3}{2}_q+\binom{3}{1}_q\right)+\binom{4}{1}_q\right)\tag{$\rightarrow 3.1$}\\
&=q^6\left(q^4\binom{3}{1}_q+q^2\binom{3}{1}_q+\binom{4}{1}_q\right)\tag{$\rightarrow 3.3$}\\
&=q^6\left(q^4\left(1+q+q^2\right)+q^2\left(1+q+q^2\right)+\left(1+q+q^2+q^3\right)\right)\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=q^6\left(1+q+2q^2+2q^3+2q^4+q^5+q^6\right)}
\end{align*}
in accordance with a plausibility check by *[WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=SeriesCoefficient%5B%281%2Bq*x%29*%281%2Bq%5E2*x%29*%281%2Bq%5E3*x%29*%281%2Bq%5E4*x%29*%281%2Bq%5E5*x%29%2C%7Bx%2C0%2C3%7D%5D)*.